# register user returns dd

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.4 and I have second user table for companies, after long time searching and fighting with codes i finally figure it how to save data in correct table but there is 2 issues i still need to solve.

1. After user register dump_var will pop up! and except redirect to dashboard
2. Password field will not save to the database

here is my registercontroller ( as you can see i do not have any `dd();`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Company;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hash;
use Session;

class CompanyRegisterController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * Where to redirect users after registration.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $redirectTo = 'companies';

  public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('guest:company');
  }

  protected function index()
  {
    return view('auth.company-register');
  }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'company_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'manager_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:companies',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        return Company::create([
            'company_name' => Input::get('company_name'),
            'manager_name' => Input::get('manager_name'),
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);

        Session::flash('success', 'Welcome, thank you for choosing us for your advertise.');
        return redirect()->route('company.dashboard');
    }
}
```

[image: Here is image after user register (return)]

[image: This is how database looks like, all saved except password]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After user register dump_var will pop up! unless redirect to dashboard

`ModelName::create()` returns the created instance and you are returning the result of it. So it makes sense. You even commented your method like so: `@return User`. If you don't want to return the created user:

```
protected function create(Request $request)
{
    Company::create([
        'company_name' => Input::get('company_name'),
        'manager_name' => Input::get('manager_name'),
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->Password)
    ]);

    return 'Something else, a string or a view for example';
}
```

> Password field will not save to the database

When you validate the password you wrote `'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'` so I deduce that you named the password field `password`. Although when you create the user you are trying to retrieve a field named `Password` through `$request->Password`. Note the capital letter. Should not the "P" be lowercase?

Update:

This answer is completly correct and I just forgot to add `password` field in my model to be fillable

```
protected $fillable = [
    'company_name', 'manager_name', 'username', 'email', 'image', 'about', 'address', 'password',
];
```

Comment: Hi @louisfischer thanks for your answer I already fixed capital `P` and added `return redirect()->route('company.dashboard');` but still same result, will return dd(), and not save the password

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider updating your question so that people who want to help you would not look in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks man I fix it and also update your answer so other people can know where was the second issue, might help others.

Comment: You are still returning the result of `Company::Create()`. Remove the `return` in front of it.